# GeoServer WMS Request - How to use alternate style?

Tags: geoserver

I have a GeoServer map request for which I want to use an alternate style...

https://xyz.com/geoserver/wms?LAYERS=earth:WAYS&CQL_FILTER=[(USAGE IN ('X'))]&STYLES=STYLE2&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SRS=EPSG:4326&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&_OLSALT=0.89383&BBOX=0,0,45,45&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256

I get back a  No such style: STYLE2

If I run the request at the GeoServer layer preview and change the style in the URL, I get back the proper result. It's just that it doesn't work when I try it through my network call. I can change the style in the network call URL to the built-in 'point' style and it works without problem. The only thing I can think of is that Geoserver is not looking in my workspace for the style, but rather the built-in, generic workspace where 'point' is stored. Perhaps there is a prefix I can place on the styles parameter, such as: ...&styles=earth:STYLE2... Tried that, but it didn't work. I think I also tried defining STYLE2 as a secondary style in the layer, but that didn't work either. The style is definitely created as I can see it in the GUI list of styles and it works in the layer preview.

Any ideas for the proper syntax or what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What's the name of the style as presented to you in the GetCapabilities  response for xyz.com/geoserver/wms

Answer (score 2):

If you have placed the style in the `earth` workspace then it should work using `earth:style2`. However you could also use the workspace specific endpoint (which is what the preview does) try changing  the start of your URL to `https://xyz/com/geoserver/earth/wms` at which point you can leave off the prefixes for layers and styles.